# Laravel 5.3 : Undefined variable in view

Tags: php, laravel

I got message Undefined variable

> Undefined variable: pesan (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

This my controller

```
...

public function index(){
  $data = DB::table('data_peminjaman')->get();
  $inventaris = DB::table('inventaris')->get();
  $posting = DB::table('artikel')->get();
  $pesan = null;
  $semuanya = ['posting' => $posting,
                'pesan' => $pesan,
                'data' => $data,
                '$inventaris' => $inventaris];
  return view('welcome', $semuanya);
}

...
```

This is my blade code

```
 @if ($pesan !=null)
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ $pesan }}
    </div>
 @endif
```

Comment: You didn’t return $pesan

Comment: $semuanya['pesan']

Comment: Talking to the database is not a job for a controller but for a model.

Answer (score 0):

Return your array this way in your controller:

```
return view('FOLDER_NAME.BLADE_FILE_NAME')->with($semuanya);
```

And then try this in your blade file:

```
@if(!empty($pesan))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ $pesan }}
    </div>
@endif
```